# String tokenizer, sanitize input?

Tags: java, string, validation

I'm working on a program that takes in book records in the form

```
<book #>,<name>,<publisher>
```

for example

```
123,Example Book,Publisher
```

After which, the user is returned to a menu, using numbers to select what option they would like.

i get an `java.util.InputMismatchException` on this menu, whenever the string is taken in with a space. such as in the example above with 'Example Book'. whereas if it were 'ExampleBook' i would get no such error.

Is there some other way to get the input?
For the string I've been using `keyboard.next()`, which doesn't pick up the `\n` and i think that may be the problem.

Comment: Could you post a more complete code snippet of exactly how you're getting this string? It's not at all clear what `keyboard` is.

Comment: You've got to specify a valid delimiter for `Scanner`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example on how to use scanner class

```
    String s = "1,1n,1b\n2,2n,2b\n2,2n,2b\n";
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(s);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        String[] sa = sc.nextLine().split(",");
        sb.append("nr:\t").append(sa[0]).append("\n");
        sb.append("\tbook name:\t").append(sa[1]).append("\n");
        sb.append("\tpublisher:\t").append(sa[2]).append("\n");
    }

    System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

This prints out:

```
nr: 1
    book name:  1n
    publisher:  1b
nr: 2
    book name:  2n
    publisher:  2b
nr: 2
    book name:  2n
    publisher:  2b
```

Note when using a file, don't forget to close it after:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("input.data"));
...
sc.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

From the docs for [StringTokenizer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html)

> StringTokenizer is a legacy class that
>   is retained for compatibility reasons
>   although its use is discouraged in new
>   code. It is recommended that anyone
>   seeking this functionality use the
>   split  method of String or the
>   java.util.regex package instead.

what happens if you uses something like [String.split()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) it should return a list of Strings in an array and you can work when them? Sorry without showing any code its difficult to suggest an improvement. PS: Whats a keyboard?

Comment: It doesn't ever throw `InputMisMatchException` and doesn't have `next()` method. So he's certainly not using the legacy `StringTokenizer` class :)

Answer (score 0):

As stated in its [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29), the [`java.util.Scanner`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29) uses a default delimiter of **whitespace**. The line `123,Example Book,Publisher` will be interpreted as two lines: `123,Example` and `Book,Publisher`. Most likely you're calling `next()` only once (which returns the first part) and then when moving to a menu, calling another next method, maybe a [`nextInt()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29) which should return some chosen menu item number. But instead it attempts to return the second part which it couldn't parse/convert to an `int` at all and thus throws [`InputMismatchException`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/InputMismatchException.html).

There are several ways to solve this. The easiest solution would be to let the scanner delimit input by newlines instead of whitespace (which not only covers newlines, but also spaces and tabs and some more special whitespace).

```
keyboard.useDelimiter("\n");
```

Further, your input-checking and exception handling should be made more robust to avoid future `InputMismatchException`s. Make use of [`hasNext()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext%28%29) methods and its type-specific counterpars like [`hasNextInt()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt%28%29) whenever possible.

That said, don't call a `Scanner` a [`StringTokenizer`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html). That's only confusing to others ;)